# Index on jsonb that have an array of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, jsonb

How could I create an index like this

```
CREATE INDEX index_companies_on_addresses_on_zipcode ON companies USING gin ((addresses -> 'zipcode'));
```

using the syntax of migrations?

I've created using the syntax below and it was created on database

```
execute "CREATE INDEX index_companies_on_addresses_on_zipcode ON companies USING gin ((addresses -> 'zipcode'));"
```

but when I saw schema.rb index wasn't there.

I've tried

```
add_index :companies, :addresses, using: :gin
```

but it create an index only on column addresses(is a jsonb) not on key zipcode.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there's no way to make [`add_index`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_index) understand that sort of indexing. Fear not, there are ways around this. You're using `jsonb` so there's no need to worry about database portability so you can switch from `db/schema.rb` to `db/structure.sql` for managing your schema. The `db/structure.sql` file is pretty much a native SQL dump of your database structure so it will contain everything that the database understands (CHECK constraints, advanced indexes, ...).

The process is quite simple:

1. Edit `config/application.rb` to set the schema format:

   ```
   class Application < Rails::Application
     #...
     config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
     #...
   end
   ```
2. Run your migration that uses `execute` as normal. You'll want to use separate [`up` and `down` methods](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#using-the-up-down-methods) in your migrations or [`reversible`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#using-reversible) inside the usual `change` method because ActiveRecord won't know how to reverse `execute some_raw_sql` on its own.
3. This should leave you with a `db/structure.sql` file so add that to your revision control and delete `db/schema.rb`.
4. Use different `rake` tasks for working with `structure.sql` instead of `schema.rb`:

   - `db:structure:dump` instead of `db:schema:dump`
   - `db:structure:load` instead of `db:schema:load`